# How to encode ObjectID in MongoDB or Strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, decode, encode

How to encode ObjectID in MongoDB or just strings in general.
I want to encode this ObjectID that I have in MongoDB
`5c8c8927c9c093b288acf44e`
so that later on I can decode it and get the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) technique.
Its an symmetric encryption algorithm.

You can encode and decode strings with 1 password.